# Deutsche Börse Public Dataset empty Body

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, bucket

I'm trying to get data from aws s3 public bucket

https://registry.opendata.aws/deutsche-boerse-pds/

When I read s3 object with `.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')` it returns only csv headers without data.

Here is the code.

```
csv_obj = bucket.Object(key ='2020-03-03/2020-03-03_BINS_XETR23.csv').get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_obj))
```

This is result in pandas dataframe with only headers.

[image]

Comment: maybe there are only headers in this file. Did you try get it in different way?

Comment: if I use on Linux `aws s3 ls 's3://deutsche-boerse-xetra-pds/2020-03-03/2020-03-03_BINS_XETR23.csv' --no-sign-request` then it shows that it has only 136 bytes - so it may have only headers

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Mint I installed `awscli`

```
apt install awscli
```

and run this command to get this file

```
aws s3 cp 's3://deutsche-boerse-xetra-pds/2020-03-03/2020-03-03_BINS_XETR23.csv' 'output.csv' --no-sign-request
```

and it has only headers

```
ISIN,Mnemonic,SecurityDesc,SecurityType,Currency,SecurityID,Date,Time,StartPrice,MaxPrice,MinPrice,EndPrice,TradedVolume,NumberOfTrades
```

If I list folder

```
aws s3 ls 's3://deutsche-boerse-xetra-pds/2020-03-03/' --no-sign-request
```

then is shows many files with only `136` bytes

```
2020-03-04 01:28:34        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR00.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:34        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR01.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:34        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR02.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:35        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR03.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:34        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR04.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:34        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR05.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:35        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR06.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:35        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR07.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:35    1965131 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR08.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:35    1647770 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR09.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:36    1483041 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR10.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:36    1416702 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR11.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:36    1587076 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR12.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:36    1235456 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR13.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:37    1430611 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR14.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:37    1792793 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR15.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:37    1303415 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR16.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:37        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR17.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:38        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR18.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:38        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR19.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:38        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR20.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:38        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR21.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:39        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR22.csv
2020-03-04 01:28:39        136 2020-03-03_BINS_XETR23.csv
```

so there are many files which have only headers

Comment: AWS S3 bucket of Deutsche Boerse is not maintained anymore. Are there alternatives?